# robot simulator for indigo

Tags: simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to test out the Basic Nav2D Widget from nav2djs and will need a to use the pr2_simulator to run the demo. I understand that the p2r_simulator have yet to be ported over to indigo. Is there any other simulator currently available on indigo which I could use?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201111/robot-simulator-for-indigo/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2015-01-19**:
Is Nav2D only available on Indigo? Could you link me to the tutorial you're trying to run?

**Comment by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on 2015-01-26**:
Sorry for the late reply. This is the tutorial i am trying to run, http://wiki.ros.org/nav2djs/Tutorials/CreatingABasicNav2DWidget. Nav2D is a web based java script lib, I am using the simulator to run test on the widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get its answer here [aueb.gr](http://www.aueb.gr/users/ion/docs/ecai2008_indigo.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [amelia22](https://answers.ros.org/users/21392/amelia22/) with karma: 16 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0